Window leak — is this a simple recaulking or do I need to new flashing?
Have a leaky double window in the basement right in the center of the frame. The caulking is cracked, and there’s a water stain on the ceiling. I’m a new homeowner and we noticed it during a heavy storm, when the rain must have been hitting the house at just the right angle — we’ve had rain before without leaks.
Here are images: https://imgur.com/a/vPo7ZgN
I could use help with a diagnosis and next steps. Would simply recaulking the flashing likely fix it? I noticed the flashing was slightly loose and detached from the window on one side. I also can’t tell if the flashing is one piece with the panel that abuts the siding.
Appreciate the help!

That looks like the window was installed improperly over the siding.  It probably need to be removed and reinstalled .  More pics of the sides where the siding intersects would help.
